# Proof that $E=E_{+}\oplus E_{-}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $w$ be a involution in a vector space $E$, and give $E_{+}=\{x\in E : wx=x\} $, $E_{-}=\{x\in E: wx=-x\} $
Well I prove that $E_{+}$ and $E_{-} $ are subspaces of E

Now is clearly that $E_{+}\cap E_{-}=\{0\}$ but I can not proof that

$$E=E_{+}\oplus E_{-}$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$x = \frac{x+wx}{2} + \frac{x-wx}{2}$$for all $x \in E$, with $$w\left(\frac{x+wx}{2}\right)=\frac{x+wx}{2} \qquad \mbox{and}\qquad w\left(\frac{x-wx}{2}\right)=\frac{-x+wx}{2}. $$

Comment: You were faster by 1 min. (+1). Will delete my answer.

Comment: And if I write $x=wx+o$ is this correct? By proof that

Comment: No. You don't know whether $x \in E_+$ to begin with. On the other hand, if you write $x = x_++x_-$ and *impose* that $x_{\pm} \in E_{\pm}$, you can actually show that $x_+$ and $x_-$ are given by the expressions above.